# airodump-ng doesn't show SSID

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, kali-linux

So I have installed Kali on a Virtualbox VM which is running on a host of Ubuntu.

Kali version:`Kali 2022.3 kali-rolling`

I am using a TP Link archer external wifi adapter. It can easily go to monitor mode on the host system. I have passed it into the Virtualbox and it shows up in the `lsusb` command in the guest OS (kali).

`TP-Link Archer T9UH v1 [Realtek RTL8814AU]`

Now I have installed all the drivers and stuff for RTL8814AU chipset

Driver Version `realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms 5.6.4.2-git20220606.cab` from kali apt repo

`airmon-ng check kill` kills the wpa_supplicant

`airmon-ng start wlan0` converts the adapter to monitor mode.

`airmon-ng` can detect the wlan card and the interface is set to `wlan0`. Even `iwconfig` shows the device. But both my system Network Manager and `airodump-ng` can't find any SSID upon scan. `iwlist` also doesn't show any SSID. So in essence the guest system (Kali) detected the physical card but can't use it for some reason.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My friend I tried to answer earlier but it didn't go through. I had the same issue as you and managed to make it work today.
You shouldn't run check kill and everything works fine when you start your device it turns to wlan0mon at least in my case that is the name and then I can directly scan with airodump without any killing of processes.
Hope it helps.
Give it a try and tell me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, you need configure the Oracle VM: File – Settings – Proxy – select Direct Connection to Internet
- Then you configure your Kali Linux VM: plug your network adapter in USB – go to Settings – in Net select Bridge mode – in USB you must add your network adapter – then edit the filter, Remote must be No
- Then, VERY IMPORTANT, UNPLUG YOUR NETWORK ADAPTER FROM USB
- After that start your Kali Linux VM
- After the Kali Linux being ready, then, just then, PLUG YOUR NETWORK ADAPTER IN USB
- In this point you are going to listen 2 noises, one for the connection in the host e other for the connection in VM
- You can check the status in Devices – USB, you must see your network adapter already selected
- Try the airodump routine, it has good chances to work